# Delete row after insert trigger without error

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know how could I delete a row from same table after the condition is set without getting the error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger,
I set this trigger in customers table for column amount:

```
DELETE FROM customers where new.amount=0.00
```

Is it possible what I am trying to reach? How could I make it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modifying the same table from the trigger would cause an infinite loop, and that's why it can't be done that way. Also, your statement is wrong as well. `new.amount` stores the **value** to be stored in `amount` column. What you said with your statement is similar to `DELETE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE 0.00 = 0.00;`. The solution is to re-think what you want to do and tell us the whole story, so we can come up with the alternative.

Comment: Hi N.B., regarding new.amount its because this has to be checking only the latest row, what I need is that if new.amount is 0.00 then I need to delete that new row from customers table.

Comment: So basically, if the value of `amount` to be inserted is `0.00`, you don't want to proceed with inserting? Is this to disallow `0.00` to be entered?

Comment: In that case, you use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. You check with `IF` whether `NEW.amount` is `0.00` and if yes, you use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) to abort the insert. Your (scripting) language will interpret the SIGNAL as an `Exception`.